# Spring Security 3.1 Authorization

Tags: spring-security, authorization

I want to use spring security in my existing web application.Currently I can authenticate the user. But I can not to do authorization. The application gives 403 -error. What am I missing? please help . My applicationContext-securty.xml as below

```
<http use-expressions="true" >
        <!--<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" /> -->
         <intercept-url pattern="/pages/test_for_admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/main/scenarios.bak" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <!-- <form-login/>-->
        <form-login login-page="/login.bak" default-target-url="/pages/main/scenarios.bak"/>
        <logout />

    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
        <authentication-provider >
            <!-- <password-encoder hash="md5" /> -->
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password,enabled FROM web_users WHERE username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username,authority FROM web_authorities WHERE username = ?"                   
                role-prefix="ROLE_" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the URL that you direct Spring after login. In this case it is

```
default-target-url="/pages/main/scenarios.bak
```

Is it a valid URL? what do you see in the browser's address bar when you get the 403 forbidden?

HTH